# MudBlazor Total Sum calculation based on Start and End Date

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I'm learning Blazor and I have started to develop this blazor page. In which I'm trying to calculate the total sum, based on the number of days between start date and End Date multiplied by the Room.Price (get from another model).
The Total Sum should be automatically filled in, after the user has inserted arrival date and departure date.

```
@page "/createbooking"
@inject HttpClient httpClient
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject StateContainer StateContainer
@inject GlobalStateContainer globalStateContainer
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@implements IDisposable
@inject ISnackbar snackBar

<EditForm Model="transactionModelForCreation" OnValidSubmit="BookRoom">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <MudPaper>
        <MudCard Outlined="true">
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudTextField Label="UserName" Immediate=true Variant="Variant.Text"
                              Value="username" ReadOnly=true />

                <MudTextField Label="Room Type" Immediate=true Variant="Variant.Text" Value="roomType" ReadOnly=true />

                <MudDatePicker Label="Arrival Date"
                               Date="transactionParameters.DateOfArrival"
                               Required=true RequiredError="Arrival Date is required!"
                               PickerVariant="PickerVariant.Dialog" Rounded="true"
                               Elevation="1" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" MinDate=DateTime.Now.Date
                               Validation="@transactionParameters.ValidDateRange" />

                <MudSpacer></MudSpacer>
                <div onblur="CalculateTotalSum">
                    <MudDatePicker Label="Departure Date"
                                   Date="transactionParameters.DateOfDeparture"
                                   DateChanged="CalculateTotalSum"
                                   onfocusout="CalculateTotalSum"
                                   Required=true RequiredError="Departure Date is required!"
                                   PickerVariant="PickerVariant.Dialog" Rounded="true"
                                   Elevation="12" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" MinDate=DateTime.Now.Date
                                   Validation="@transactionParameters.ValidDateRange" />

                </div>

                <MudTextField Label="Total Sum"
                              @bind-Value="totalSum"
                              Variant="Variant.Text" />

            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudText>Create Booking and go to Payment page</MudText>
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto" OnClick="() => BookRoom()">Book</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudPaper>


</EditForm>
    

@code {
    TransactionDataForCreationDto? transactionModelForCreation { get; set; } = new();
    RoomDto? RoomDetailsDto { get; set; } = new();
    TransactionParameters transactionParameters { get; set; } = new();    

    public event Action? OnStateChange;
    string? username = "";
    string? roomType = "";
    int totalSum = 0;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user?.Identity is not null)
        {
            username = user.Identity.Name;
        }

        transactionParameters = new TransactionParameters
        {
            DateOfArrival = DateTime.Today,
            DateOfDeparture = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
        };
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        RoomDetailsDto = StateContainer.Value;
        if (RoomDetailsDto is not null)
        {
            roomType = RoomDetailsDto.RoomType;            
            var dateRange = new TransactionDataForCreationDto { Room = RoomDetailsDto, ApplicationUserId = username, RoomId = RoomDetailsDto.Id, ArrivalDate = transactionParameters.DateOfArrival, DepartureDate = transactionParameters.DateOfDeparture };
            totalSum = (int)dateRange.TotalSum;
        }

        
    }

    private void CalculateTotalSum()
    {
        if (RoomDetailsDto is not null && transactionParameters != null)
        {
            var dateRange = new TransactionDataForCreationDto {Room = RoomDetailsDto, ApplicationUserId = username, RoomId = RoomDetailsDto.Id, ArrivalDate = transactionParameters.DateOfArrival, DepartureDate = transactionParameters.DateOfDeparture };
            totalSum = (int)dateRange.TotalSum;
        }
    }

    async Task BookRoom()
    {
        transactionModelForCreation.ApplicationUserId = username;
        transactionModelForCreation.RoomId = RoomDetailsDto.Id;


        await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/transactions", transactionModelForCreation);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("payment");// a new page for paying the booking will be created
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
       globalStateContainer.OnStateChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }

}
```

This is the transaction Parameters class

```
namespace HotelManagementSystem.Shared.RequestFeatures
{
    public class TransactionParameters
    {
        public DateTime? DateOfArrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfDeparture { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// check that DepartureDate is greater than ArrivalDate
        /// </summary>        
        public bool ValidDateRange => DateOfDeparture > DateOfArrival;        
    }
}
```

This is the TransactionDataForCreationDto

```
    public class TransactionDataForCreationDto
    {

        private int totalSum;
        public RoomDto Room { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// User id
        /// </summary>
        public string? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Room Id
        /// </summary>
        public Guid RoomId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Booking start date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? ArrivalDate {get; set;}


        /// <summary>
        /// booking end date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? DepartureDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Transaction sum
        /// </summary>
        public double TotalSum
        {
            get
            {
                if (Room != null && DepartureDate is not null && ArrivalDate is not null)
                {
                    return (int)(Room.Price * ((DateTime)DepartureDate - (DateTime)ArrivalDate).TotalDays); //calculate the total sum                
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Room));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So the problem is in here. When the Arrival and Departure dates are filled in. I expect TotalSum to be calculated based on the the number of days between arrival and departure * Room.Price.
DateChanged is fired when changing the Departure Date. But when it goes to CalculateTotalSum, it returns the value only for one day.

```
private void CalculateTotalSum()
    {
        if (RoomDetailsDto is not null && transactionParameters != null)
        {
            var dateRange = new TransactionDataForCreationDto {Room = RoomDetailsDto, ApplicationUserId = username, RoomId = RoomDetailsDto.Id, ArrivalDate = transactionParameters.DateOfArrival, DepartureDate = transactionParameters.DateOfDeparture };
            totalSum = (int)dateRange.TotalSum;
        }
    }
```

I've initialized transactionParameters with current day, cause when I was using it without, it was returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateChanged is an EventCallback<T> so when it's fired it passes data along with it. This data is commonly called an event payload.

From the [docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/datepicker#eventcallbacks) DateChanged fires an `EventCallback<DateTime?>` and from the looks of it you're trying to use the new departureDate, that means you must handle that new changed value in your `CalculateTotalSum` method.

```
private void CalculateTotalSum(DateTime? changedDateOfDeparture) //method needs to take in the payload
{
  if (RoomDetailsDto is not null && transactionParameters != null) 
  {
    var dateRange = new TransactionDataForCreationDto 
    {
      Room = RoomDetailsDto,
      ApplicationUserId = username,
      RoomId = RoomDetailsDto.Id,
      ArrivalDate = transactionParameters.DateOfArrival,
      DepartureDate = changedDateOfDeparture // changed date needs to go here. 
    };
    totalSum = (int) dateRange.TotalSum;
  }
  transactionParameters.DateOfDeparture = changedDateOfDeparture ; // change to update the MudDatePicker Date
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly I was missing.